# How to detect if image is present on screen?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, detection

Here is the image I need to detect: http://s13.postimg.org/wt8qxoco3/image.png

Here is the base64 representation: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TZQUieWe

The reason why I'm asking for your help is because this is a complex problem and I am not equipped to solve it. It will probably take me a week to do it by myself.

Some pseudo-code that I thought about:

1) Take screenshot of the app and store it as image object.

2) Convert binary64 representation of my image to image object.

3) Use some sort of algorithm/function to compare both image objects.

By on screen, I mean in an app. I have the app's window name and the PID.

To be 100% clear, I need to essentially detect if image1 is inside image2. image1 is the image I gave in the OP. image2 is a screenshot of a window.

Comment: On screen, where?  In a browser, on your desktop, in an app?

Comment: @sberry: Actually, ignore what I said earlier. In an app. I have the window name of the app and the PID.

Comment: SURF detector is perfect for your needs. Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10987035/723891)

Comment: You need to detect that an exact pixel-by-pixel copy of the image, right? If not, this is a whole lot harder.

Comment: @abarnert: No unfortunately. I need to essentially detect if image1 is inside image2. image1 is the image I gave in the OP. image2 is a screenshot of a window.

Comment: @Igonato: It doesn't seem like there is an actual algorithm for comparing the two. It only seems to color the number of points that match between the two.

Comment: Yes, but by "is inside", you mean "there's an exactly pixel-for-pixel copy of image1 somewhere in image2", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you break this down into pieces, they're all pretty simple.

First, you need a screenshot of the app's window as a 2D array of pixels. There are a variety of different ways to do this in a platform-specific way, but you didn't mention what platform you're on, so… let's just grab the whole screen, using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm):

```
screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
haystack = screenshot.load()
```

Now, you need to convert your base64 into an image. Taking a quick look at it, it's clearly just an encoded PNG file. So:

```
decoded = data.decode('base64')
f = cStringIO.StringIO(decoded)
image = Image.open(f)
needle = image.load()
```

Now you've got a 2D array of pixels, and you want to see if it exists in another 2D array. There are faster ways to do this—using `numpy` is probably best—but there's also a dumb brute-force way, which is a lot simpler to understand: just iterate the rows of `haystack`; for each one, iterate the columns, and see if you find a run of bytes that matches the first row of `needle`. If so, keep going through the rest of the rows until you either finish all of `needle`, in which case you return `True`, or find a mismatch, in which case you `continue` and just start again on the next row.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Awesome needle/haystack analogy. I should've thought of that myself. I asked the question pretty poorly.

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting this error: NameError: name 'data' is not defined I'm using an import, aren't I?

Comment: Oh, `data` is the base64 data you read from wherever. If it's a local file, just do `with open('data.b64') as f: data = f.read()`. If it's on the web, use `urllib2` or `requests`. And so on.

Comment: BTW, I didn't come up with the "needle/haystack" thing. I'm not sure who did, but the documentation for a pretty wide variety of languages—Smalltalk, PHP, Haskell, …—use them as the parameter names for find/search functions.

Comment: Meanwhile, did you figure out everything you _do_ need to import? It should just be `import cStringIO`, `from PIL import Image`, and `from PIL import ImageGrab`… but PIL's package/module structure is a bit funky, so if that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: So I'm using this code: http://pastebin.com/0q7C9XZM but I'm getting this error TypeError: 'PixelAccess' object is not iterable for line 3. By the way, the total number of pixels is 980 for the image that I'm using.

Comment: Right, you can't directly iterate a PIL pixel access array, and you also can't access the rows as real objects; you have to do `for rowidx in range(screenshot.size[1]): for colidx in range(screenshot.size[0]): pix = haystack[rowidx, colidx]`. (Or something like that.) It may be easier to just copy them both into some better data structure. If you can use `numpy`/`scipy`, a 2D `ndarray` is probably the best data structure, and someone's probably already written the code for you, and it'll be an order of magnitude faster too.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably the best place to start:

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

if you don't have access to the image's meta data, file name, type, etc, what you're trying to do is very difficult, but your pseudo sounds on-point. essentially, you'll have to create an algorithmic model based on a photo's shapes, lines, size, colors, etc. then you'd have to match that model against models already made and indexed in some database. hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, if you decode his base64, it's just an entire PNG file, so he has access to everything he needs to convert it into an array of pixels with PIL. So, this works.

Comment: Why would it be easier if I had access to the image's meta data? To be 100% clear, I need to essentially detect if image1 is inside image2. image1 is the image I gave in the OP. image2 is a screenshot of a window. image2 won't have any metadata because it's a screenshot only.

Comment: @user1251385: I think he's saying you need the metadata to figure out how to map the bits to pixels. (In other words, you need the PNG header, which you have.)

Comment: abarnert, extactly. for some reason i was under the impression this was for random images. it sounds like you might not need image detection to do what you're talking about doing. for instance, you could set up a function that registers if a screenshot has been taken. again, i'm not sure what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like https://python-pillow.org/ is a more updated version of PIL.

Comment: It's better to use comments for answers like these. If you want to add them as an answer, then please include the relevant details that are needed to completely answer the questions. Thanks and have a great day.