# SURF descriptors with opencv 2.4.6.1 and Python

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I'm playing around with SURF-feature detection using Python and opencv. I have found these examples here on stackoverflow [OpenCV 2.4.1 - computing SURF descriptors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984313/opencv-2-4-1-computing-surf-descriptors-in-python), but unfortunately they are not working with newest version of opencv namely 2.4.6.1. The cv2.SURF.detect() command must have been changed, because it now allows only two arguments now:

```
cv2.SURF.detect(image[, mask]) → keypoints¶
```

So i can just get the keypoints, but how do i get the descriptors? Did not find a solution for that. Hope you can help me here. Thanks

Comment: try this: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html#surf and this: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher and this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the tutorial posted by Abid Rahman K in comments, i modified this example code [OpenCV 2.4.1 - computing SURF descriptors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984313/opencv-2-4-1-computing-surf-descriptors-in-python) so it is working with opencv 2.4.6.1

the function for getting SURF keypoints and descriptors has been changed to:

```
cv2.SURF.detectAndCompute(image, mask[, descriptors[, useProvidedKeypoints]]) → keypoints, descriptors
```

So here is the modified example of the link:

```
import cv2
import numpy

opencv_haystack =cv2.imread('haystack.jpg')
opencv_needle =cv2.imread('needle.jpg')

ngrey = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_needle, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hgrey = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_haystack, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# build feature detector and descriptor extractor
hessian_threshold = 5000
detector = cv2.SURF(hessian_threshold)
hkeypoints,hdescriptors = detector.detectAndCompute(hgrey,None)
nkeypoints,ndescriptors = detector.detectAndCompute(ngrey,None)

# extract vectors of size 64 from raw descriptors numpy arrays
rowsize = len(hdescriptors) / len(hkeypoints)
if rowsize > 1:
    hrows = numpy.array(hdescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((-1, rowsize))
    nrows = numpy.array(ndescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((-1, rowsize))
    #print hrows.shape, nrows.shape
else:
    hrows = numpy.array(hdescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32)
    nrows = numpy.array(ndescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32)
    rowsize = len(hrows[0])

# kNN training - learn mapping from hrow to hkeypoints index
samples = hrows
responses = numpy.arange(len(hkeypoints), dtype = numpy.float32)
#print len(samples), len(responses)
knn = cv2.KNearest()
knn.train(samples,responses)

# retrieve index and value through enumeration
for i, descriptor in enumerate(nrows):
    descriptor = numpy.array(descriptor, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((1, rowsize))
    #print i, descriptor.shape, samples[0].shape
    retval, results, neigh_resp, dists = knn.find_nearest(descriptor, 1)
    res, dist =  int(results[0][0]), dists[0][0]
    #print res, dist

    if dist < 0.1:
        # draw matched keypoints in red color
        color = (0, 0, 255)
    else:
        # draw unmatched in blue color
        color = (255, 0, 0)
    # draw matched key points on haystack image
    x,y = hkeypoints[res].pt
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    cv2.circle(opencv_haystack,center,2,color,-1)
    # draw matched key points on needle image
    x,y = nkeypoints[i].pt
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    cv2.circle(opencv_needle,center,2,color,-1)

cv2.imshow('haystack',opencv_haystack)
cv2.imshow('needle',opencv_needle)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think code can be more simplified than this. Please read following tutorials in the same link I provided.